# Sendgrid v3 not working for me with rails my_mailer.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I want to send a transactional mail via Sendgrid when a user registers (I use devise for authentication). I had this working fine in my_mailer.rb using SMTP as follows:

```
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    # SMTP header for Sendgrid - v2
    # headers["X-SMTPAPI"]= {
    #  "sub": {
    #    "-CONFIRM_TOKEN-": [
    #      token
    #    ]       
    #   },
    #  "filters": {
    #   "templates": {
    #     "settings": {
    #       "enable": 1,
    #       "template_id": "1111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
    #     }
    #   }
    #  }   
    # }.to_json
```

However, prompted by Sendgrid to use v3 syntax to support newer mail templates, I changed code to the following (from the sendgrid help docs, as opposed to a real understanding):

```
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})

    require 'sendgrid-ruby'
    include SendGrid

    sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])

    data = JSON.parse('{
      "substitutions": {
        "-CONFIRM_TOKEN-": [
          token
        ],
      "template_id": "1111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
    }')

    response = sg.client.mail._("send").post(request_body: data)
    puts response.status_code
    puts response.body
    puts response.parsed_body
    puts response.headers
```

Now I get the error message:
   `` 'NoMethodError (undefined method `include' for #<MyMailer:0x0000000003cfa398>):' ``

If I comment out the 'include' line I get:
    `'TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):' on the line: "sg = SendGrid..."`

I use the Gem:  sendgrid-ruby (5.3.0)

Any ideas would be appreciated - I've been trying to hit on the correct syntax by trial-and-error for a while now and finally admit I am stuck.

**UPDATE#1:**
The first issue was I was using the wrong API_KEY env. variable (copied from 2 different help docs): "SENDGRID_API_KEY" (in code) vs. SENDGRID_APIKEY_GENERAL (set in Heroku). Fixed.

**UPDATE #2:**
With the "include" line commented out I now seem to be getting a JSON parse error:

`JSON::ParserError (416: unexpected token at 'token`

So my 2 current issues are now:
 (1) I would like 'token' to be the confirmation token variable but it is not being passed

(2) Sending the below simple (1 line) content of 'data' does not throw up an error, but the appropriate template within Sendgrid is not selected:

```
data = JSON.parse('{
  "template_id": "1111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"    
}')
```

**UPDATE #3:**
Here's an update on the status of my issue and exactly where I am now stuck:

This code works fine (using Sendgrid v2 which I am trying to upgrade from):

```
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})

    #
    # SMTP header for Sendgrid     - v2
    #     This works fine
    #

    headers["X-SMTPAPI"]= {
     "sub": {
       "-CONFIRM_TOKEN-": [
         token
       ]
      },
     "filters": {
      "templates": {
        "settings": {
          "enable": 1,
          "template_id": "1111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
        }
      }
     }
    }.to_json
```

This Sendgrid v3 code does not work (the email does get sent via Sendgrid but it does not select the template within Sendgrid - it just uses whatever code is in app/views/my_mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb):

```
    #
    # Sendgrid API v3
    #   This sends an email alright but it takes content from app/views/my_mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
    #   It DOES NOT select the template within Sendgrid
    #

    data = JSON.parse('{
      "template_id": "1111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
      "personalizations": [
        {
          "substitutions": {
            "-CONFIRM_TOKEN-": "'+token+'"
          } 
        }
      ]
    }')

    sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_APIKEY_GENERAL2'])
    response = sg.client.mail._("send").post(request_body: data)
    puts response.status_code
    puts response.body
    puts response.parsed_body
    puts response.headers
```

As always, any insight appreciated.

Comment: You should ask a new question, not update an answered question. Also if you feel like you were helped you should accept and upvote answers :-)

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer as it was a help (to solve the specific 'include' problem), but I do not have enough reputation to do so.  Also, my original issue was still not resolved which is to get a transactional dynamic template working with SendGrid v3.  In the meantime I have made some progress which I will document now as an answer to help others doing the same.

Comment: I updated my answer, I think you made a mistake using `JSON.parse` and that you are not actually calling the right mailer method from your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to get SendGrid v3 API working with Ruby/Devise/Heroku and use SendGrid's dynamic transactional emails these tips may help you. I spent a week getting this to work and these steps (& mistakes I made) were not apparent in the various documentation:

1. Generating the SendGrid API key (on SendGrid website): when generating the key, the API key only appears once allowing you to copy it, from then on it is invisible. As I could not see the key later I mistakenly used the "API Key ID" in my Heroku environment variables, rather than the true API Key.
2. Ensure the name you give the key in Heroku (for me: "SENDGRID_APIKEY_GENERAL") matches the code you use to reference it i.e. sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_APIKEY_GENERAL'])
3. For sending variables to be substituted in the template use "dynamic_template_data" and not "substitutions".  This should be within the "personalizations" section (see code example below).
4. I found it useful to refer to the Sendgrid dynamic template ID by using an environment variable in Heroku (for me: 'SENDGRID_TRANS_EMAIL_CONFIRM_TEMPLATE_ID') as opposed to hard-coding in Ruby (just allowed me to experiment with different templates rather than changing code).
5. The correct syntax for using a variable in the JSON string in Ruby is e.g.             "CONFIRM_TOKEN": "'+token+'"   (see code example below)
6. Do not use other characters in the name:  i.e. "CONFIRM_TOKEN"  worked but "-CONFIRM_TOKEN-" did not work
7. In the HTML of the transactional email template on SendGrid use this syntax for the substitution:  {{CONFIRM_TOKEN}}
8. When creating a transactional template on SendGrid you can only have a 'design' view or a 'code' view not both. You must select at the start when creating the template and cannot switch after.
9. In the devise confirmations_instructions action refer to the user as a record (e.g. email) as record.email
10. Gemfile:   **gem 'rails', '5.2.2'**      *ruby  '2.6.1'*      **gem 'devise', '4.6.1'**        *gem 'sendgrid-ruby', '6.0.0'*

Here is my successful ruby code that I have in my_mailer.rb:

```
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})

    data = JSON.parse('{
      "personalizations": [
        {
          "to": [
            {
              "email": "'+record.email+'"
            }
          ],
          "subject": "Some nice subject line content",
          "dynamic_template_data": {
            "CONFIRM_TOKEN": "'+token+'",
            "TEST_DATA": "hello"
          }
        }
      ],
      "from": {
        "email": "aaaa@aaaa.com"
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text/plain",
          "value": "and easy to do anywhere, even with Ruby"
        }
      ],
      "template_id": "'+ENV['SENDGRID_TRANS_EMAIL_CONFIRM_TEMPLATE_ID']+'"
    }')

    sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_APIKEY_GENERAL'])
    response = sg.client.mail._("send").post(request_body: data)
    puts response.status_code
    puts response.body
    puts response.headers
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `include` a module in a method. You have to include it in your class, so outside of the methode, like

```
class SomethingMailer
  require 'sendgrid-ruby'
  include SendGrid

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    ...
  end
end
```

For your third update problem:

You are not sending a JSON but instead you are creating a JSON, then parsing it into a hash, then sending that hash, instead of the JSON.

```
JSON.parse #parses a JSON into a Hash
```

You should do the opposite and have a hash that you transform into a JSON

Something like

```
data = {
  template_id: your_template_id # or pass a string
  personalizations: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Then you call

```
data_json = data.to_json
response = sg.client.mail._("send").post(request_body: data_json)
```

However this does not explain why your template  in `app/views/my_mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb` gets sent. So I think you are either calling a different mailer_method at the same time, or you are not calling your actual confirmation_instructions method at all. Try to confirm that you SendGrid Methods actually is called and see what it returns. It should have returned some kind of error before, when you were sending a hash instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks -  I updated my code accordingly.  Latest issues as per my Update #3.